# how to use a javascript variable in django if statement

Tags: javascript, html, django, if-statement

My code is

```
<body>
    <div class="slideshow">
      {% for img in image_pr %}
      {% if img.section == section %}
      <div class="slideshow_img" style="background-image:url(/static/images/project_images/{{img.name}}.jpg)">
      </div>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
        var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }

    var section = getParameterByName('section');

    </script>
  </body>
```

i would like to use the variable name "section" in the if statement used in body. How can i do it?

Comment: django runs on server and javascript runs in browser ... they know nothing about each other as they run in completely different environments and at different times

Comment: You can't.  Take a step back and consider what you're trying to accomplish, as there will be a different way to accomplish it.  What's the underlying goal here?